# django-pytest is not using configs mentioned in pytest.ini

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I am using pytest-django for the unit test cases for my django app. I have created pytest.ini in the root directory (same level as manage.py) with the following configs:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MDOULE = mysite.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts = --reuse-db
```

Whenever I run command pytest in my root directory, it is giving me the following error:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/aakash/Desktop/experiments/repos/organonconnect/conftest.py'.
conftest.py:4: in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py:2: in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py:47: in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:103: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:252: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:134: in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:79: in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:64: in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
E   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

However whenever I run `pytest --ds=mysite.settings`, it works fine but without the configs mentioned in pytest.ini.

I have created a conftest.py at the same level as pytest.ini and I am using Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
django_find_project = True
```

Add this to your `pytest.ini`.

**EDIT:**
It looks like you have spelled `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` wrong in your `pytest.ini`. Please fix it.

Comment: I added `django_find_project = True` in my pytest.ini file under the pytest stanza. Is that correct? Still, it is giving me the same error. And regarding settings module, my project is called mysite so it's right. Sorry for the confusion in the decription, I will change it.

Comment: Please post your `conftest.py`. I think there's an error in it. **EDIT:** I changed the answer, please consult it.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the typo now, it is working fine now. I feel so stupid, anyways thanks a lot.:)

Answer (score 1):

You have this issue because **pytest-django** is not installed in addition to your django project.

Do

`pip install pytest-django`

Excute `pytest` again

Answer (score 0):

Pytest has an order of precedence when choosing which settings.py to be used in tests and the settings in the pytest.ini is only used as last resort.

Pytest first looks at the `--ds` setting when running your tests, if that is not set it then used the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`,  if this also not set it uses the settings set in the `pytest.ini` file.

source: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html